# How do I keep a div/image from scrolling when the user scrolls?

Tags: image, html, scroll, position, visible

The solution I built works great in most browsers, but not in IE. I'm looking for a solution that works in all browsers. Preferably not needing jQuery. Here is what I have working so far:

https://www.casemodo.com/order_fabric_01_pick_design.asp <-- click a fabric option then on the next page click "ipad2" and then you will be on the page that has an image on the left that I want to stay visible when the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

`position: fixed` works similarly to `absolute`, but is relative to the viewport

Comment: Not sure what you are recommending as far as IE vs. other browsers?